# Bulk insert of MySQL related tables from bash

Tags: mysql, bash

I need to upload regularly quite a bulk of data to a MySQL database from CSV files. I used do this by simply executing LOAD DATA INFILE from bash scripts. Now however, the data are to be spread over several tables and relations are to be kept. What are general strategies in such cases?

Let's assume an initially simple task: relation one-to-many, two tables.

I consider something like:

1. getting maximal identyfier for table 1
2. manually applying identifiers to the CSV file
3. splitting the file with two target tables in mind
4. inserting both tables

Is it an optimal solution? (In the real case for example I'm going to have lots of many-to-many relations to be updated this way.)

Can I lock the table 1 from the level of bash for the duration of whole the process? Or do I have to use some intermediary tool like perl or Python to keep all the things in one session?

Comment: Excellent first post! Your answer depends on if you're an Immon(ite) or a Kimball(ite), Kimball's Data warehouse Toolkit (book) (http://www.amazon.com/The-Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Dimensional/dp/0471200247/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1334075383&sr=1-1 ) argues to leave the artifical keys to be generated by the system. Or try an alternate approach that has worked well for me. Keep a set of separate 'input' tables, import current file to the empty input table, then run stored procedure to merge into main tables. Good luck.

Comment: Use awk to preprocess/split the data and just `load data` on the split files. If you want more details, you'll have to provide some yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are various conflicting requirements expressed in your question. This answer concentrates on the “keep lock” aspect of it.

In order to maintain a table lock for the whole operation, you'll have to maintain a single connection to the sql server. One way would be passing everything as a multi-line multi-command input to a single invocation of the mysql command line client. Basically like this:

```
{ echo "LOCK TABLES Table1 WRITE"
  for i in "${infiles[@]}"; do
    echo "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '${i}'"
  done
} | mysql
```

That would work as long as you can generate all the required statements without asking questions from the database (like maximal identifier) while the lock is kept.

In order to mix read operations (like asking for a maximal value) and write operations (like loading content of some files), you'll nead a bidirectional communication with the server. Achieving this through bash is very tricky, so I'd advise against it. Even if you don't need to ask questions, the unidirectional connection provided by a bash pipe is a source of danger: If anything goes wrong on the mysql side, bash won't notice and will issue the next command anyway. You might end up committing inconsistent data.

For these reasons, I'd rather suggest some scripting language for which mysql bindings are available, like the Perl or Pyhon options you mentioned. Reading CVS files in those languages is easy, so you might do all of the following in a single script:

1. lock tables
2. start transaction
3. read input csv files
4. ask questions like max id
5. adjust input data to match table layout
6. insert data into tables
7. if no errors occurred, commit transaction